# Probability at temperature in system has energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, frequency, probability, normal-modes

Salutations, I'm starting in statistical mechanics and reviewing some related studying cases I would like to understand what occurs in small systems with normal modes of vibration, for example, a small system that has 2 normal modes of vibration, with natural frequencies $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2=2\omega_1$. So, what would be the probability at a temperature T that the system would get an energy less than $5\omega_1/2$? if it's assumed the zero of energy is taken as its value at $T=0$.

I would like any guidance for better understanding of that kind of cases because those problems are very interesting, specially how to approach them.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Landau-Lifshitz book on statistical mechanics (volume 1), chapter 12 (in 3rd edition) about fluctuations has proper treatment of this.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your commentary, about your suggestion, I have been looking for the mentioned reference but I haven't been lucky, I don't find that volume of Landau-Lifshitz, I would like you to share the download link or the part of book that approaches that topic, please. Thanks for your commentary and attention.